# Discrepancy between git log --stat and git show --stat?

Tags: git, parsing, github, version-control

I am working on an [R package](https://github.com/lorenzwalthert/gitsum) that is supposed to parse git repository history on a granular level. When validating some of the parsing results with an [open source project from GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr), I encountered something unexpected. In previous validation efforts of my package, I managed reconstruct the number of lines of each file in several git repositories correctly via the output of git log, so I thought using `git log` to obtain comprehensive information about changed files is a valid path to follow.
However, I found a commit in the aforementioned [project](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr) where git log does not seem to convey all information about changed files: The commit with the hash `184f6c71dee03c66c7adaacb024b70d99075ea75`. When resetting HEAD to this commit and running both `git log --stat` and `git show --log`, I get this:

```
$ git log --stat
commit 184f6c71dee03c66c7adaacb024b70d99075ea75
Merge: 32e47a3 d203300
Author: ***
Date:   Wed Nov 12 10:39:51 2014 +0100

    merge changes from master branch

commit d203300bbe45981dab15b49c3c08deb31ad46466
Merge: 4b63f4e c8ae895
Author: ***
Date:   Wed Nov 12 10:35:36 2014 +0100

[ output truncated ]

commit 32e47a32f3cc60b5705e9df93cdc6b730fae380b
Author: ***
Date:   Tue Nov 11 18:00:55 2014 +0100

    Added the internal class template `MatrixColumnVisitor` to represent
      `VectorVisitor` concept for a column that is a `matrix`. Part of #602

 NEWS.md                                  |   3 +++
 inst/include/dplyr.h                     |   1 +
 inst/include/dplyr/MatrixColumnVisitor.h | 167 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 inst/include/dplyr/VectorVisitorImpl.h   |   4 +++-
 inst/include/dplyr/visitor.h             |  17 ++++++++++++++---
 inst/include/dplyr/white_list.h          |   4 ++++
 tests/testthat/test-filter.r             |  12 ++++++++++++
 7 files changed, 204 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)

[ output truncated ]
```

And

```
$ git show --stat
commit 184f6c71dee03c66c7adaacb024b70d99075ea75
Merge: 32e47a3 d203300
Author: ***
Date:   Wed Nov 12 10:39:51 2014 +0100

    merge changes from master branch

 NEWS.md                                        |  4 ++--
 R/RcppExports.R                                |  4 ++++
 R/src-sql.r                                    |  2 +-
 inst/include/dplyr/NamedListAccumulator.h      | 12 ++++++------
 inst/include/dplyr/Result/LazyGroupedSubsets.h |  4 ++--
 inst/include/dplyr/Result/LazySubsets.h        |  4 ++--
 inst/include/dplyr/Result/Name.h               | 46 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 inst/include/dplyr/Result/all.h                |  1 +
 src/RcppExports.cpp                            | 15 +++++++++++++++
 src/dplyr.cpp                                  | 29 ++++++++---------------------
 src/strings_addresses.cpp                      | 19 +++++++++++++++++++
 tests/testthat/test-joins.r                    |  7 +++++++
 tests/testthat/test-mutate.r                   | 18 ++++++++++++++++++
 13 files changed, 131 insertions(+), 34 deletions(-)
```

This was surprising because I thought

```
git log --stat
```

And

```
git show --stat
```

give me the same information. 
This is not the case, since from the `git log` output, I conclude that there were no files changed in the commit of interest.

When viewing the commit [on GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/184f6c71dee03c66c7adaacb024b70d99075ea75#diff-7060a3128044caf1d3c4f2a2c25a5d65) or in the RStudio git tab, I can see that this commit was not empty, i.e. the information showed with `git show` seems correct and it appears to me that there is information missing with `git log` for that commit.

Any idea why there is this discrepancy? As pointed out, for a large amount of commits, I can correctly reproduce the number of lines of each file in a git repository from `git log`, but not for this one. I am runnig git 2.9.2 on macOS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `git log` *skips* showing diffs for merge commits, while `git show` shows *combined diffs* for merge commits.  Adding `--cc` (show combined diffs) to the `git log` options tells `git log` to show combined diffs (or stats for them) for merges.

Note that combine diffs have limited usefulness.  For proper analysis you may want `-m`, which is an option that both `git log` and `git show` accept.  It tells the commands to, in effect, split each merge into multiple virtual commits.  A merge commit has *n* parents where *n ≥ 2*, and `-m` makes Git turn *commit A with parents P1, P2, ..., Pn* into *commit A-P1 with parent P1; commit A-P2 with parent P2; ...; commit A-Pn with parent Pn*, then show (or `--stat`) each of those commits individually.

Comment: thanks @torek. So from your answer, I conclude that it is sensible to continue to use `git log` as a starting point for parsing? So setting the `-m` option in addition to what I do already (`--stat --parents`)?

Comment: It's fine if it produces what you want. Many internal Git commands are scripted using `git rev-list`, which is very similar to `git log` except that it mostly just outputs hash IDs, from which you can do even more. If you need very detailed output, or even output in more machine-parseable form, you might want to use the various "plumbing" commands (rev-list, diff-tree, and so on).